# how to make a text ele to the right of a left floated ele automatically occupy the rest width?

Tags: css

```
<div style="width:<?php echo $w; ?>">
    <div style="float:left;margin-right:10px;width:200px">whatever</div>
    <h2 style="border-bottom:solid 1px black">title</h2>
</div>
```

By default, the width of `h2` would be `$w`, and the bottom border will strike the inner div, I want the h2 to automatically occupy the rest width, no matter what `$w`'s value is, the h2's width should be `$w - 200 - 10`. How to achieve this in pure CSS?

PS: if I set css `h2{float:left}`, h2's width would depend on its inner text's length. To have the `h2` element occupy the rest of the width (so that I can have a beautiful bottom border) I have to manually set a width value for h2, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats),

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an
>   element in the normal flow that establishes a new [block formatting
>   context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must
>   not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting
>   context as the element itself.

Therefore, you can just add

```css
h2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 500px; /* $w */
}
div > div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
h2 {
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>whatever</div>
  <h2>title</h2>
</div>
```

You may also want to style the outer `div` with `overflow: hidden` just in case the floated element is taller than the `h2`.